# Python cx_Freeze - One Executable file does not open the other?

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

tss.py --> this file contains a subprocess that open another python file (dark.py)

```
import subprocess as sp

def process():
    programName = "python.exe"
    fileName = "dark.py"
    sp.Popen([programName, fileName])

process()
```

This functions works when i execute it as a .py file on the console. However, when I create 2 Executable form (tss.exe and dark.exe) using cx_Freeze and open tss.exe, it does not open the other dark.exe file.

below is the setup.py file used to build the python file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

tclDLL = r'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll'
tkDLL = r'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll'

Packages = ["subprocess","tkinter"]
Include_Files = ["icon.ico", "dark.ico",tclDLL, tkDLL]

build_exe_options = {"packages": Packages, "include_files": Include_Files}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'

setup(  name = "TSS",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Tournament Scoring System",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("tss.py", base=base, icon="icon.ico")
                       Executable("dark.py", base=base, icon="dark.ico")])
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming `fileName = "dark.py"` to `fileName = "dark.exe"` in your script.

Remember that that you are converting your .py file into an executable format ie .exe so you must launch your exe file not a .py file that will not work on another computer.

So it should look like:

```
import subprocess as sp

def process():
    fileName = "dark.exe"
    sp.call(fileName)

process()
```